# What is the value of $\lim_{x\to0^+}(\sqrt{x})/(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}} -2)$?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}(\sqrt{x})/(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}} -2)$$

I have tried multiplying it out by the conjugate but that still leaves me with zero in the denominator.

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}(\sqrt{x}*(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}+2))/(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}} -4)$$

Comment: Could you show the result of multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate?

Comment: Hint: cancel something after multiplying.

Comment: You need to multiply out the denominator more carefully.  What you just posted is not correct.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. When you multiply $A-B$ by $A+B$, the result is $A^2 - B^2$. You've written $A-B^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}-2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}-2} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}+2}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}+2}$

$= \dfrac{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}+2)}{(4+\sqrt{x})-2^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}+2)}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Do you see any factor in both the numerator and denominator that cancels out?

Comment: how did you simplify the second to last one to the last, how does the 2^2 cancel out?

Comment: $4+\sqrt{x}-2^2 = 4+\sqrt{x}-4 = \sqrt{x}$

Comment: is it ok to remove the parentheses like that?

Comment: Addition/subtraction are commutative+associative, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}} - 2} = \sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}} + 2 \rightarrow 4$

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using Taylor series. Rewrite $$\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4}}$$ and remember that, when $y$ is small $\sqrt{1+y}\simeq 1+\frac{y}{2}$. Replace now $y$ by $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4}$. So $$\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}-2\simeq2\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4}\Big)-2=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4}$$ This is the denominator.

I am sure that you can take from here.